# Как установить новые темы ttk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, ttk

Я нашёл темы для ttk: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes
Есть ссылка для скачивания. Я скачал. Куда распокавать файлы .tcl? Или требуется какая-нибудь утилита? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Под Linux вроде бы вот тут темы ttk лежат: `/usr/share/tcltk/tk8.6/ttk`. Под Windows сам tcl лежит внутри папки Python. ttk темы вроде бы тут : `c:\Python36\tcl\tk8.6\ttk\`. Будет ли работать тема, если ее просто положить в такую папку - нужно пробовать.

Comment: Нет, я это сначала делал. Но ничего не вышло...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ очевиден. Достаточно копировать .tcl файлы сюда:

```
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python(version)\tcl\tk8.6\ttk
```

Или сюда:

```
C:\Python(version)\tcl\tk8.6\ttk
```

И установить библиотеку ttkthemes:
`pip install ttkthemes` или `py -m pip install ttkthemes` в cmd

Импортировать `ThemedStyle`:

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
```

создать стиль:

```
style = ThemedStyle()
```

И присвоить стиль:

```
style.set_theme("scidgrey")
```