# Как установить темы для Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где и как можно скачать темы для Tkinter. А то системных не хватает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip3 install ttkthemes
```

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = ThemedTk()
root.set_theme("arc")#or something other
b = ttk.Button(root, text="hi")
b.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: А где можно посмотреть весь список тем?

Comment: @DGDays https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes

Comment: Можно ли скачать темы из этого списка: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes  на windows?

Comment: @DGDays https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-ttk

Comment: Вообще не работает( Установил все как в инструкции, пробовал и через ttk.Style и через ThemedStyle(), нтчего не помогает. Постоянно пишет ошибку:  _tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::aqua

Comment: @DGDays Тема aqua работает только на маке.

Comment: Но у меня вообще ни одна не работала. Мы с вами на эту тему уже говорили) На данный момент связался с разработчиком модуля ttkthemes, он сказал что попробует их добавить в своой модуль. Осталось только ждать.