# Как правильно установить темы для Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, tkinter, tcl

Как правильно установить темы для Tkinter отсюда в Windows: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/List+of+ttk+Themes ??? Эту ссылку не кидать([Как установить новые темы ttk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1043999/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-ttk)), т.к. пробовал уже и ничего не вышло.

---

Вот строки кода из tcl файла, которые отвечают за открытие png:

```
    proc LoadImages {imgdir} {
    variable I
    foreach file [glob -directory $imgdir *.png] {
        set img [file tail [file rootname $file]]
        set I($img) [image create photo -file $file -format png]
        }
    }

    LoadImages [file join [file dirname [info script]] i breeze]
```

Comment: Почему не вышло, что не получилось?

Comment: @Jazzis, tcl тема держится на png и она не может их найти

Comment: @Jazzis, часть кода добавлена в вопрос

Comment: А где у вас лежат .png-файлы относительно файла темы? Судя по коду, в той же папке, где лежит файл `breeze.tcl` должны быть папки `i/breeze/`, а в ней уже сами `*.png` файлы.

Comment: @Jazzis, они лежат рядом с кодом в папке i/breeze. Я даже уже изменял код чисто на одну папку breeze и всё равно ничего не работает

Comment: А подключать тему пытаетесь через `ttkthemes`?

Comment: @Jazzis, через ttkthemes пытался подключить. Он писал ошибку: _tkinter.TclError: can't find package ttk::theme::breeze

Comment: Тема лежит в нужной папке, но почему-то не работает. А если посмотреть темы через питон, то её там не будет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт.
Связался с разработчиком ttkthemes, он сказал что добавит новые темы.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, можно не запускать